# Is there a way I can mantain the state of a boolean, even when I close the widget?

Tags: flutter

So, in this code, I need that isDarkModeEnabled keeps it's state, so when I load the widget, the switch appears as by the theme (In dark mode, dark, in light mode, light.)

I'm using this plugin, it's basically a switch. (https://pub.dev/packages/day_night_switcher)

The code:

```
import 'package:day_night_switcher/day_night_switcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:velneoapp/main.dart';

/// The main widget.
class DayNight extends StatefulWidget {
  const DayNight({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DayNightState();
}

/// The main widget state.
class DayNightState extends State<DayNight> {
  bool isDarkModeEnabled = true;

  /// Whether dark mode is enabled.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Dark mode")),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Changes from dark mode to light mode, and vice-versa',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            DayNightSwitcher(
              isDarkModeEnabled: isDarkModeEnabled,
              onStateChanged: (isDarkModeEnabledVar) {
                if (isDarkModeEnabledVar == false) {
                  MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.light);
                } else {
                  MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.dark);
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[The switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDk4m.png)

[The problem, only happens when you re-enter the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGPaT.png)

I tried setting the state in init state, but it keep repeating one time after the other.

Comment: check out state management in flutter, like riverpod, getx, bloc etc.

Comment: Yes, that answered my question. I didn't found that one, thanks a lot for helping me!